# In what way is logging within a method error-prone and intrusive?

Tags: c#, aop

I am reading the book [Adaptive Code via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735683204), and the author, Gary McLean Hall, says:

> [Logging, and Transactional Code,] is laborious and error-prone, and it instantly pollutes every
>   method with irrelevant boilerplate code, increasing the
>   noise-to-signal ratio. Instead, you can factor out such cross-cutting
>   concerns into encapsulated functionality and apply them to the code in
>   a much less invasive fashion. The most common way of adding
>   functionality non-invasively is through aspect-oriented programming.

For this code:

> ```
> public void OpenNewAccount(Guid ownerID, string accountName, decimal openingBalance)
> {
>     log.WriteInfo("Creating new account for owner {0} with name '{1}' and an opening balance of {2}", ownerID, accountName, openingBalance");
>
>     using(var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
>     {
>         var user = userRepository.GetByID(ownerID);
>         user.CreateAccount(accountName);
>         var account = user.FindAccount(accountName);
>         account.SetBalance(opening Balance);
>
>         transaction.Commit();
>     }
> }
> ```

I understand that it is laborious, and that it does things that the method name doesn’t indicate, such as logging, but I couldn’t see why it is error-prone. Maybe because you are repeating yourself a lot?

His suggestion is to use this code instead:

> ```
> [Logged]
> [Transactional]
> public void OpenNewAccount(Guid ownerID, string accountName, decimal openingBalance)
> {
>     var user = userRepository.GetByID(ownerID);
>     user.CreateAccount(accountName);
>     var account = user.FindAccount(accountName);
>     account.SetBalance(opening Balance);
> }
> ```

But if you are simply looking for a generic logger, then you can call a method like `_log.Log()`, which is relatively the same amount of work. Unless attributes have the capability to inspect method implementation, I don’t see much value in them in cases like this except that they provide slightly more descriptive code.

Comment: There appears to be a stray quotation mark at the end of `log.WriteInfo` in the first code block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the [cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) of the logging example.  This is considered cross cutting because the logging strategy affects every part of the logged system (at least it has to take it into account).  In that regard something that needs to be taken into account by every part of the system, means that to change logging means that you **could** have to change every part of the system that logs, (for instance to add more relevant information).  (Also, you could call it error prone if you forgot to log something important).  In practice logging is usually benign, so it makes for a lackluster example and a stretch to call it error prone.

I think a better example would have been checking security.  I don't think it is much of a stretch to see how cutting and pasting security code all over could be error prone, and updates to that code could become difficult to get correct.

If you need to change the way that security/permissions are implemented (in the non-Aspect world) you (Could conceivably) need to revisit every place that does a security check, simply because security checks are scattered throughout the program.  The entangled design makes it difficult from a design/maintenance point of view to account for all possible interactions.  If you have a [CheckSecurity] attribute then there is minimal entanglement and never a need to revisit each function that needs to check security.

The key here is that Aspects will alter code at compile time/run time based on inspection.  So, if you need to change how security credentials are checked you only have to go to one location in your code. This is significantly different from just having a single method/function to do security checks, because functions cannot inspect their stack and alter their behavior based on who is calling.  Code injection in c# can.

Here is a PostSharp [example1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS)  [example2](https://www.postsharp.net/aspects) and a [podcast](http://www.hanselminutes.com/213/aspect-oriented-programming-aop-and-linfu-with-philip-laureano)

Comment: Good description, nice links and cool podcast for a podcast fan like myself. +1

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the author that it is error-prone. One very important reason is simplicity. Just by eye-balling the two samples you have given here, it is clear that the second implementation is much easier to maintain and understand. Imagine adding a new parameter to the method: (I am assuming the Logged attribute takes care of logging the parameters also), if you were to log it inside the method with code, you have to mentally parse the format string, add the parameter etc and any change made is error-prone. Also, when you write this code in multiple methods, it is easy for someone to miss some parameters and/or pass in the parameters in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you need your code to perform several actions for an operation it is a source of potential bugs if you forget one or botch the arguments. It is especially true if the code you add is repetitive but not identical. Do it in a dozen places and it all start looking the same. It will take you a long time to pinpoint that you forgot to change an argument when you copy/pasted the code from somewhere else.

Declarative approach as is used with attributes eliminates all these sources of bugs. You won't recognize the benefits until you spend a few hours chasing a bug only to discover you forgot to edit after copy/paste. It is an experience thing and very much dependent on size of code you are working with. For small code there is no difference and adding explicit code is easier to follow, especially when your are learning. On large code bases, with lots of maintenance each line introduces a potential for a bug because every change in nearby code may require a change in the boiler plate code.

As far as polluting the code, it is also true. You have to skim over these to focus on the main purpose of the code. Boilerplate code just gets in the way. Again, magnitude depends on size and complexity of the codebase.

I suggest you do what works for you and when it starts feeling like there has to be a better way then re-read old recommendations and see if they make more sense now. Trying to absorb it as a hypothetical concern is almost impossible and won't make sense until you get battle scars, making it personal and relevant.